# Группировка по неделям в промежутке разных годов mysql

Tags: mysql, запрос, select, group-by

Возник такой вопрос, по группировке по неделям:
Если взять промежуток 01.12.2018 - 01.06.2019, то получается результат запроса по группировке по неделям будет:

```
01.12-02.12
03.12-09.12
10.12-16.12
17.12-23.12
24.12-30.12
31.12
01.01-06.01
```

как объеденить два последних результат в один результат, это же одна и та же неделя, просто из-за того что 53 и 1 это разные недели в числовом понятии, как сделать правильно, чтобы оно учитывало это как целую неделю, а не разбивало на два отрезка?

Comment: а как учесть понедельник любой, не сильно понятно, можете подсказать?

Comment: вроде бы понял, спасибо

Comment: все-таки оказалось не совсем понятно, например есть вот такой запрос
select updated, count(1) 
from products 
where updated >= '2018-12-01' and updated <  '2019-01-15' 
group by week(updated, 1), как его правильно исправить

Comment: всеравно получается не то, что хочу, но ладно

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/Zssod8RjiFKD8rt3c7s3S/5
должен быть вот такой результат:
15.12 - 1 - 1
17.12 - 4 - 3
24.12 - 3 - 4
31.12 - 5 - 2
07.01 - 2 - 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот fiddle protocol. Разбирайтесь.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (dt DATETIME, val INT)
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO test 
> WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
> SELECT '2019-01-01' dt
> UNION ALL
> SELECT dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY
> FROM cte
> WHERE dt < '2019-02-01'
> )
> SELECT dt, ROUND(10 * RAND())
> FROM cte
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM test
> ```
>
> ```
> dt                  | val
> :------------------ | --:
> 2019-01-01 00:00:00 |   4
> 2019-01-02 00:00:00 |   5
> 2019-01-03 00:00:00 |   1
> 2019-01-04 00:00:00 |   0
> 2019-01-05 00:00:00 |   8
> 2019-01-06 00:00:00 |   9
> 2019-01-07 00:00:00 |   3
> 2019-01-08 00:00:00 |   7
> 2019-01-09 00:00:00 |   6
> 2019-01-10 00:00:00 |  10
> 2019-01-11 00:00:00 |   1
> 2019-01-12 00:00:00 |   6
> 2019-01-13 00:00:00 |   6
> 2019-01-14 00:00:00 |   3
> 2019-01-15 00:00:00 |   7
> 2019-01-16 00:00:00 |   5
> 2019-01-17 00:00:00 |   2
> 2019-01-18 00:00:00 |   9
> 2019-01-19 00:00:00 |   6
> 2019-01-20 00:00:00 |   5
> 2019-01-21 00:00:00 |   4
> 2019-01-22 00:00:00 |   8
> 2019-01-23 00:00:00 |   5
> 2019-01-24 00:00:00 |   4
> 2019-01-25 00:00:00 |   6
> 2019-01-26 00:00:00 |   5
> 2019-01-27 00:00:00 |   6
> 2019-01-28 00:00:00 |   7
> 2019-01-29 00:00:00 |   5
> 2019-01-30 00:00:00 |   7
> 2019-01-31 00:00:00 |   8
> 2019-02-01 00:00:00 |   9
> ```

> ```
> SELECT MIN(dt) `from`, MAX(dt) till, SUM(val) `sum`
> FROM test
> GROUP BY DATEDIFF(dt, '2018-12-31') DIV 7
> -- литеральный эталонный понедельник 31 декабря 2018 года
> ```
>
> ```
> from                | till                | sum
> :------------------ | :------------------ | --:
> 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | 2019-01-06 00:00:00 |  27
> 2019-01-07 00:00:00 | 2019-01-13 00:00:00 |  39
> 2019-01-14 00:00:00 | 2019-01-20 00:00:00 |  37
> 2019-01-21 00:00:00 | 2019-01-27 00:00:00 |  38
> 2019-01-28 00:00:00 | 2019-02-01 00:00:00 |  36
> ```

> ```
> SELECT MIN(dt) `from`, MAX(dt) till, SUM(val) `sum`
> FROM test
> GROUP BY DATEDIFF(dt, (SELECT MIN(dt) - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(MIN(dt)) DAY 
>                        FROM test)) DIV 7
> -- вычисляемый эталонный понедельник
> ```
>
> ```
> from                | till                | sum
> :------------------ | :------------------ | --:
> 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | 2019-01-06 00:00:00 |  27
> 2019-01-07 00:00:00 | 2019-01-13 00:00:00 |  39
> 2019-01-14 00:00:00 | 2019-01-20 00:00:00 |  37
> 2019-01-21 00:00:00 | 2019-01-27 00:00:00 |  38
> 2019-01-28 00:00:00 | 2019-02-01 00:00:00 |  36
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ff57465f11f094480b3cdea1e297d339)*

Применительно к авторскому fiddle:

```
SELECT MIN(updated), MAX(updated), SUM(status = 1), SUM(status = 2)
FROM products
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(updated, (SELECT MIN(updated) - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(MIN(updated)) DAY 
                            FROM products)) DIV 7;
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/Zssod8RjiFKD8rt3c7s3S/6)

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться тогда